# how to run a java rmi program in the property of a jsp button

Tags: java, jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@page import="com.studytrails.tutorials.springremotingrmiclient.TestSpringRemotingRmi" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="red">
    <h1><font color=blue>login successfull</font></h1>
    <h2><font color="lightgreen">
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyServlet" method="post">

    <input type=submit name="n1" value="Click here to play the video">

    </form>

    </h2>

    </body>
    </html>

Need to run the below program when clicking the button in jsp file.


    package com.studytrails.tutorials.springremotingrmiclient;
    import java.io.*;

    import java.io.File.*;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

    import com.studytrails.tutorials.springremotingrmiserver.*;


    public class TestSpringRemotingRmi 
    {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
         {
                ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config-client.xml");
                GreetingService greetingService = (GreetingService)context.getBean("greetingService");

                String greetingMessage = greetingService.getGreeting("Alpha");

                System.out.println("The greeting message is : " + greetingMessage);
                greetingService.getText();
         }   

    }
```

In above program I am trying to run java  `TestSpringRemotingRmi`  class in the time of button click performed in jsp file. MyServlet file contains the code for process the request from jsp file. but I try to call the default constructor of that call using jsp but it does not work. guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: i just did using main() method